# Create an Event class using wait/notify

Tags: java, concurrency

Here is an exam question I scored badly in before but am trying to get it right this time around. I would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction, thanks.

My questions is, is the provided solution in any way correct to solve the problem? How could it be improved.

My code follows the question.

Question:

> An event object has one of two states signaled or non-signaled. When
>   the event is in the signaled state all or one waiting threads are
>   released. When it is reset to the non-signaled state all the user
>   threads will be forced to wait. An event stays in the signaled state
>   until it is reset to the non-signaled state. The basic idea is that
>   one or more threads can wait for some event to happen. When the event
>   waited for occurs the threads take whatever action is required. Using
>   wait/notify write an Event class.

My Attempt:

```
class Event  {
    boolean signal;
    String obj = new String();

    public Event(boolean signal) {
        this.signal = signal;
    }
    synchronized void getSignal(){
        while(!signal)
            try{
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    public void setSignal(boolean signal) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.signal = signal;
            this.notifyAll();           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code correct and if not, can it be improved?

Comment: Does it do what it's supposed to?

Comment: Yes, but strangely enough I was crucified for this in an assignment. I'm beginning to think there is negative marking as I wrote some other code to make use of Event. Maybe that's where I fell down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this test class which I think answers the subject, and my Event is somehow similar to yours.

A thread is waiting for the event to happened (when signaled), then wait for the reset while another thread is activating and deactivating the signal, from time to time.

**Edit:** I wasn't aware of your simple question so maybe this code is useless for you.
Anyway, your Event class should work, so what can I say ?

```
public class SynchronizationTest {

public class Event  {

    boolean signal = false;
    synchronized String getEvent(){
        while(!signal) {
            try{
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        return "This is an event";
    }

    synchronized public void waitNextEvent(){
        while(signal) {
            try{
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    synchronized public void setSignal(boolean signal) {
        this.signal = signal;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}

class EventChecker extends Thread {

    private Event event;
    public EventChecker(Event event) {
       this.event=event;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            String eventStr = event.getEvent();
            System.out.println("EventChecker: Got event '"+eventStr+"'");
            System.out.println("EventChecker: wait for new event.. \n");
            event.waitNextEvent();
        }
    }
}

class EventSignaler extends Thread {

    private Event event;
    public EventSignaler(Event event) {
       this.event=event;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            event.setSignal(true);
            System.out.print("EventSignaler: Sending new signal\n");
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random()*2200));
            } catch(Exception e){}

            event.setSignal(false);
            System.out.print("EventSignaler: Deactivating signal\n\n");
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random()*4200));
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
       }
    }
}

public void startTest() {

    Event event=new Event();
       EventSignaler eventSignaler = new EventSignaler(event);
       EventChecker eventChecker=new EventChecker(event);
       eventSignaler.start();
       eventChecker.start();
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    SynchronizationTest synchro = new SynchronizationTest();
    synchro.startTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would correctly answer the question you posed.

There are a few slight optimizations that could be done:

- The `setSignal()` method can be synchronized, removing the need for the extra synchronized code region.
- The `notifyAll()` wakes up all `wait()`'ing threads even when the signal state hasn't been changed.  You could avoid some overhead by checking, in `setSignal()` if the signal is going from a locked/blocked to an unlocked state.  If so, you notify.  If not, do nothing.
- The `obj` is unnecessary.